# A Sequential Circuit: Mistake in Book: Figure 5.15

Tags: circuit-design

I am reading the book: [Digital Logic Design by Morris Mano](https://www.portcity.edu.bd/files/636444791235373856_Digitallogicdesign.pdf#page=223). I have a doubt in Figure 5.15 of the book. In the figure, 'y' denote the output of the circuit. However, the authors have shown it in two ways: y = A + B + x' and y = (A + B).x'. The two state equations are different. Is this a mistake in the book?

Comment: I don't see the equation y = A + B + x' anywhere in the text. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson It is not there in the text. But in the figure, A,B, and x' are input to an OR gate (very right side of the figure). That is why, I wrote y = A + B + x'. The doubt is in the figure.

Comment: Only A and B are at the input of the OR gate

Comment: @devnull See the very right side of the figure. What you saw is the bottom of the figure.

Comment: There appear to be two different signals, both labeled 'y', on the same diagram. One of them does not correspond to the text. Seems a bit sloppy, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @IY4 Ok, I see. Table 5.2 refers to the gate at the bottom. As Spehro mentioned, sloppy, to say the least.

Answer (score 2):

The two "y" are not really "equivalent" ...

Here is what "happens".

It seems that one solution detects "rising" x edge ... while the other detects "falling" x edge.

[image]